# How to cache TextureAtlas results?

Tags: caching, libgdx, sprite, texture-atlas

When using a TextureAtlas to create a Sprite with the createSprite method, the LibGDX documentation says: This method uses string comparison to find the region and constructs a new sprite, so the result should be cached rather than calling this method multiple times.

How do I cache these results? Is it just a variable I create to store the created sprite? If so then how do I create different copies of the same sprite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you use the `createSprite` method, a new `Sprite` gets created. Usually you'd have one sprite per enemy for example. Let's say that you have a class `Frog` which is one of your enemies. It should look like this (pseudo-code):

```
public class Frog {
    private Sprite sprite;

    public Frog(TextureAtlas atlas) {
        sprite = atlas.createSprite("frog");
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        // update the sprite position
    }

    public void render(Batch batch) {
        sprite.draw(batch);
    }
}
```

Now each `Frog` would have its own `Sprite`. This is necessary, since all frogs can be in different places. The position will be configured via the `Sprite`. You will create the sprite just once in the constructor and all of those sprites share the same `TextureRegion` of the same `TextureAtlas`, which will result in a good performance, since there won't be many texture switches on the graphics card, when you render your frogs.

Comment: @noone just curious, wouldn't it be better to just send the textureRegion to the frog instead of the entire atlas? Or does that not make a difference?

Comment: @MrCharli3 No, that does not make a difference, since it's only a reference to the atlas, not the atlas itself. A reference to an atlas and a reference to a texture are both just 4 byte.